# Teste unitário de atributo privado de uma classe / C#

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, ddd, moq

Estou tentando criar um teste unitário para garantir que um atributo de uma classe X seja realmente alterado. Porém para compara-ló no final do meu teste, algo como:

```
 Assert.Equal(_sampleClass.Email, mockEmail);
```

Preciso que ele tenha um valor diferente do que é setado no construtor, já que caso ele possua, nunca poderá executar o que está abaixo da condição:

```
public class SampleClass(){

    private string Id {get; private set};
    private string Name {get; private set}
    private StatusClass Status {get; private set}

    public SampleClass(string id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id,
        this.Name = name,
        this.Status = StatusClass.Accepted
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(email){

        if(this.Status == StatusClass.Accepted)
            // get out of the method

        this.Email = email;
    }
}
```

Procuro uma forma de através dos testes unitários, trocar o atributo Status da classe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse ponto é que as práticas do `TDD` vem à tona.

Essas propriedades privadas não devem ser testadas. Ou deveriam ser públicas, ou sua inacessibilidade demonstra que estão lhe faltando métodos para a consulta e ou deveriam ser testadas em um outro lugar, por não fazerem parte desta unidade de fato.

Comment: Saquei, vou revisar a lógica e entender alguma forma de testar o método em questão. Obrigado.